# Polynomials with integer coefficients that can be iterated for infinitely many times and the result is always a prime number

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

> Denote $f^{(n)}(x)=\underbrace{f(f(f(f(\cdots f}_{n \;\text{times}}(x)))))$. Does there exists a polynomial function $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $f^{(n)}(1)$ are all prime numbers, and $\forall i,j\in \mathbb{N}, f^{(i)}(1)\neq f^{(j)}(1)$?

I think we can't find a polynomial function that satisfy the above identity.

---

**Observation**:

1. $f(x)=x^2+x+1$,

$f(1)=3, f^{(2)}(1)=13, f^{(3)}(1)=183$. $3\mid 183$.$\;\;\;\;\;\times$

2. $f(x)=x^2+3x+1$,

$f(1)=5, f^{(2)}(1)=41, f^{(3)}(1)=1805$. $5\mid 1805$.$\;\;\;\;\;\times$

3. $f(x)=3x^2-x+1$,

$f(1)=3, f^{(2)}(1)=25, f^{(3)}(1)=1851$. $3\mid 1851$.$\;\;\;\;\;\times$

4. $f(x)=x^3+2x^2+x+1$,

$f(1)=5, f^{(2)}(1)=181, f^{(3)}(1)=5995445, f^{(4)}(1)=215508505260670237621$. $5\mid f^{(3)}(1)$.$\;\;\;\;\;\times$

5. $f(x)=x^3+3x^2+5x+2$,

$f(1)=11, f^{(2)}(1)=1751, f^{(3)}(1)=5377774511, f^{(4)}(1)=155527705682516977725188134751, f^{(5)}(1)=3762039024097970068792517560792353596800152524223246433216608553915834472630739126136511.$

$11\mid f^{(5)}(1)$.$\;\;\;\;\;\times$

---

After my observation, I found that at some moment, $f(1)$ always divide $f^{(n)}(1)$. How can I prove it?

**(Not a full) Proof**:

BWOC. If there exists a polynomial function $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $f^{(n)}(1)$ are all prime numbers, then $\displaystyle{f(1)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i}$ is a prime number. Notice if $f(1)=2$, then $2\nmid f^{(2)}(1)$, so $2\mid f^{(3)}(1)$, so $f(1)$ should be an odd prime number. .......

Actually, I have no idea what to do next, but I guess that proof should be highly correlated with "iteration".

**Note**:

1. $\mathbb{N}=\mathbb{Z}^+$
2. If there are mistakes in my question, I'm willing to edit it. Hope it's not a duplication.

Comment: If you mean to exclude stationary solutions like $f(x)=x^2-3x+4$ then you'll need to state that.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for advice. I will edit the question.

Comment: If $f(x)=2x+1$, then $f^{(n)}(89)$ is prime for $n=0,1,\dots,5$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain

Comment: @GerryMyerson Am I able to come up with a similar argument, but $f^{(n)}(1)$, using the Cunningham Chain?

Comment: Not if you mean $f(x)=2x+1$, that just gives you $1,3,7,15=3\times5$. $f(x)=2x+3$ gives $5,13,29,61,125=5^3$ which is a bit better. $f(x)=2x+9$ gives six primes. Probably for every $k$ there's an $n$ such that $2x+n$ gives $k$ primes. But that will be hard to prove.

Comment: Here's an observation that may or may not be useful on a restriction between $n$ and $p$. If $(f^{(n)}(1))_{n \ge 0}$ represents the prime $p$, then we have that it is eventually periodic mod $p$, but not immediately otherwise it would be $0 \mod p$ infinitely often. This forces the condition that $f^{(n)}(1)=p$ implies $n \le p-2$. For instance, if it represents $p=3$ then we know it must have the sequence $1,0,2,2,... \mod 3$, and we have $n=1 \le 3-2$.